# How to remove items from List of HashSet of int in a loop

Tags: c#

I have the following lists:

```
        var set = new List<HashSet<int>>()
        {
            new HashSet<int>() { 1,2,3,4},
            new HashSet<int>() { 1,2,3,5},
            new HashSet<int>() { 1,2,4,5},
            new HashSet<int>() {2,3,4,5}
        };

        var subSet = new List<HashSet<int>>()
        {
            new HashSet<int>() { 1,2,3},
            new HashSet<int>() { 1,2,4},
        };
```

I want to remove from set the subSet.Count() items, which isProperSubSet, and the result must be:

```
        var result= new List<HashSet<int>>()
        {
            new HashSet<int>() { 1,2,3,5},             
            new HashSet<int>() {2,3,4,5}
        };
```

How can I do it?

I tried like this, but I get an index error (must be non negative and less then the collection):

```
for(int j=set.Count-1;j-->0;)
        {
            for (int i = subSet.Count-1;i-->0;)
            {
                if (subSet[i].IsProperSubsetOf(set[j]))
                {
                    subSet.RemoveAt(i);
                    set.RemoveAt(j);
                }

            }
        }
```

Comment: Why are you doing the decrement in the comparison?  Just do `for(int j=set.Count-1;j>=0;j--)`

Comment: I still get the error in the If condition

Comment: You are doing `set.RemoveAt(j)` inside a loop and accessing `set[j]` in the same loop. The item at index j+1 has moved to index j. When j+1 == Count, you will get that error.

Comment: You need a `break` inside of your `if` so you don't access `set[j]` again after doing `set.RemoveAt(j)` in the inner loop.

Comment: @juharr, with break is working, can you please put your comment like answer

Comment: @Tim, with more items in set and subset I get the error, but using break inside the if is working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you need to break out of the inner loop once you remove a value from `set`.

```
for(int j=set.Count-1; j >= 0; j--)
{
    for (int i = subSet.Count-1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if (subSet[i].IsProperSubsetOf(set[j]))
        {
            subSet.RemoveAt(i);
            set.RemoveAt(j);
            break;
        }
     }
}
```

That's because you might still be iterating the inner loop and now your `j` will actually reference the wrong position (which might be beyond the new length of the list).

Answer (score 0):

First, you should not remove elements from `subSet` or the other elements of `set` which the subset is not a proper `subSet` won't be removed.

Second, juharr said, you have to add a break inside the if :

```
for(int j=set.Count-1;j-->0;)
    {
        for (int i = subSet.Count-1;i-->0;)
        {
            if (subSet[i].IsProperSubsetOf(set[j]))
            {
                set.RemoveAt(j);
                break;
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: It depends.  If the OP doesn't want the subset to be used to remove more than one set then they would need to remove from subset.  Your change would actually only leave one of the sets in the example given, instead of two.